# IMPORTANT onException shareUnitOfWork Apache Camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, apache-camel-3

I can't make it sharing unitofwork when using onException. I do need to use multicast and splitter. 
I have tried so far such as useOriginalMessage etc, could not make it.

```
   onException(Exception.class)
            .handled(Boolean.TRUE)
            .process(XXX)
            .marshal()
            .jacksonxml()
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .removeHeader(XXXX)
            .end();



   from(RouteDefinition.XXX)
            .id("XXX")
            .unmarshal().jacksonxml(XXX.class)
            .to("bean-validator://x")
            .setHeader(XXXS, constant(XXX.class))
            .setProperty(ApplicationParam.REQUEST_BODY, body())
            .bean(xxxx, "XXX")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethod.POST))
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .setHeader(CxfConstants.CAMEL_CXF_RS_RESPONSE_CLASS, constant(XXX.class))
            .to(restUri(jaxrsEndpoint, uri))
            .removeHeader(Header.HEADER_LIST)
            .bean(xxxx, "responseBeanXX")
            .marshal().jacksonxml();
```

The flow of process; Apache CXF -> JAXRS-> Exception -> OnException -> Processor -> Response Body

Comment: @Kavithakaran Kanapathippillai  I have added some information. Thanks for information.

Comment: Well, I guess in this point exception is not important. When Camel, onException in global creates new Thread and I can not  share unit of work. Moreover, I am using log4j2 with MDC logging. Thus, in this example, I want to log everything in exception with MDC logging.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem. I don't see any usage of UnitOfWork in your code.

Comment: Well, how can I share MDCUnitOfWork on onException definition? @burki

Comment: Maybe @Claus Ibsen help me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use [MDC logging in Camel](https://people.apache.org/%7Edkulp/camel/mdc-logging.html), you can activate it with  `camelContext.setUseMDCLogging(true);`

I don't know if this is still supported in Camel 3.x since the linked documentation page no more exists in the official Camel docs.

If you want to use UnitOfWork in your Camel Routes, check out [this page](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/oncompletion.html)

Comment: Of couse, its configured in this way., camelContext.setUseMDCLogging(true);
                ExtendedCamelContext ecc = camelContext.adapt(ExtendedCamelContext.class);
                ecc.setUnitOfWorkFactory(new MyCustomUnitOfWork());

Comment: Do you get a logging message like `MDC logging is enabled on CamelContext: [context name]`? This should be the case if it is enabled. Otherwise try to debug the application startup and check if your context configuration is called.

Comment: Shortly, i did what I configured. MDC logging is working fine btw. I have no problem in this topic. However, onException route definition unit of work class is not invoked by Camel. For example, onComplete route definition unit of work class is invoked by it. My point of this situation is that not invoking unit of work class on onException route definition

Comment: If you want to react to failed exchanges with unitOfWork, you use `onCompletion().onFailureOnly()...`

Comment: yeah I did this way :) However, the flow of my process is not compatible with this :D

Answer (score 0):

```
   DefaultErrorHandlerBuilder defaultErrorHandlerBuilder = new DefaultErrorHandlerBuilder();
    defaultErrorHandlerBuilder.setOnExceptionOccurred(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            CustomUnitOfFactory customUnitOfFactory = new CustomUnitOfFactory ();
            customUnitOfFactory .afterPropertiesConfigured(camelContext);
            customUnitOfFactory .createUnitOfWork(exchange);
        }
    });
    errorHandler(defaultErrorHandlerBuilder);
```

@burki I solved the problem with the code which is above.